# i can't import .aar file to create package in dependencies on flutter

Tags: flutter, path, aar

i can't import .aar file to create package in dependencies on flutter

> The path './android/libs/libraryCore_v1.0.8.aar' doesn't exist.
> Try creating the referenced path or using a path that exists.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  libraryCore_v1.0.8:
    path: ./android/libs/libraryCore_v1.0.8.aar
```